# Camel context restart behaviour

Tags: apache-camel

We are using camel blueprint and jboss fuse 6 for our bundle deployment.

The problem is bundle's camel context keep restarting some times and doesn't come up automatically.
Logs are showing clearly that all the routes are coming up and then all are shutting down itself and the same activity is going on infinitely.
It is difficult to trace as it is not happening consistently.

Using camel core 2.12

Comment: The bundle gets stopped because it fails on startup. Maybe something that your Camel applications depend on is not available such as some OSGi service, missing install Camel component etc.

Comment: Check the order of your bundles / features in your features.xml , you should have one if you use features command to install your app in fuse/karaf

Comment: @ClausIbsen:Is there any way I can see/know which osgi service is causing the routes to get restarted again and again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue and in my blueprint the attribute `update-strategy="reload"` on the blueprint-cm default properties was causing this to happen. I changed this to `update-strategy="none"` and this fixed the restarting behaviour.

However, this broke my blueprint tests because they relied on me being able to change properties at test-run time. If you rely on changing properties in your blueprint tests then the most reliable test method to substitute properties is the recently added (in camel-test-blueprint version 2.16.3) `setConfigAdminInitialConfiguration(Properties props)` which you can override and return a pid like you would with `useOverridePropertiesWithConfigAdmin(Dictionary props)`.

I'm using JBoss Fuse 6.2.1 and even though that camel version is 2.15.1, the test version is independent (because it's scoped to test) and you can set it to whichever you like. So even though you're using camel 2.12 I'd try with the 2.16.3 version of blueprint test.